# Changing the destination (scratch workspace) of outputs of geoprocessing tools in a model in one go,

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, scratch-workspace

Changing the destination (scratch workspace) of outputs of geoprocessing tools in a model in one go,

I couldn’t figure out the best way to change the destination (scratch workspace) of outputs of geoprocessing tools in a model in one go.

For example, if the “scratch workspace” is set to be “D:\Q.gdb” and then it is needed set it to be “D:\R.gdb”, then how this can be done?

[image]

Switching the “scratch workspace” from “D:\Q.gdb” to “D:\R.gdb” doesn’t do the job. The outputs of the tools are not directed to the “D:\R.gdb”. Is it required to change the “scratch workspace” for each tool one by one?

[image]

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: to spread some more light on the issue after a chat with the OP. One should remember that the suggested workflow will work only if the output for each tool wasn't defined; that is that tools are using the default output which is defined in the model environment settings.

#

You should continue using the model properties > workspace settings; but change both, current and scratch workspace to R.gdb. Note the following paragraphs from arcmap help:

[Scratchworkspace:](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Scratch_Workspace/001w00000003000000/)

> Tools that honor the Scratch Workspace environment setting use the specified location as the default workspace for output datasets. The Scratch Workspace is intended for output data you do not wish to maintain.

[Current workspace:](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Current_Workspace/001w00000002000000/)

> Tools that honor the Current Workspace environment setting use the workspace specified as the default location for geoprocessing tool inputs and outputs.

Note that cuurent workspace do define where the input files are, but that won't be a problem if you use a layer from the TOC or using model parameters. During model processing time, it will either get model tmp layers (i.e. make layer) or will use the outputs of tools, which have already been directed to the current workspace.

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh did it work?

Comment: Hi dof, no it doesnt work with me , have a look at the screen shots ![1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wDf7r.jpg).![2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1nGwE.jpg).
![3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1nGwE.jpg).

Comment: I have edited the scratch workspace from h to s but nothing works

Comment: I only see that you have defined the scratch and workspace but didn't see any outputs. Did you run the model afterwards?

Comment: Yes I did [4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dcdd3.jpg).

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh, I can only suggest that you edit your question, with further details, i.e. what have you changed and what are the outputs, shoq images if possible. It will help me and others to try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22994/discussion-between-dof1985-and-ahmad-saleh).